# Form Validation using jQuery with some effects

Tags: jquery

I am creating Form Validation using jQuery and I'm new to jQuery so I start to create form validation with Name,Address,Zip Code,Country,Gender,Choose Color(checkbox),Phone Number, Email, Password, Verify Password fields. As I create some code but its creating some problem as I'm Unable to get alert in else condition.Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var err = true;
    $("#submit_Button").click(function ValidateForm() {
        alert("in submit");
        if ($("#name").val() == null || $("#name").val() == "") {
            alert("in if");
            $("#name_Err").show();
            $("#name").focus();
            err = false;
        } else {
            $("#name_Err").hide();
            if (!$("#name").match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
                alert("i m in regu");
                $("#name").focus();
                err = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

css

```
  .form {
      margin - left: 450 px;
      width: auto;
      height: 500 px
  }
  .class = "left_Side" {
      text - align: left;
      width: 80 px;
      position: absolute;
      padding - left: 50 px;
  }
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();" action="" class="form">
        <table id="form_Table">
            <tr>
                <h1 style="text-align:Left; margin-left:20px;"> Javascript Validation</h1>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="name_Err">Please enter your         name</span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="na_Err">Only   alphabets</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Address :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="address" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="address_Err">Please enter your   address</span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="add_Err">Only alphabets</span> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Zip Code :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="zip_code" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="zipCode_Err">Please enter your    zip code</span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="zip_Err">Only numbers</span> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Country :</td>
                <td><select id="country_Select">
       <option value="">Select Country</option>
       <option value="opt_India">India</option>
       <option value="opt_Australia">Australia</option>
       <option value="opt_America">America</option>
      </select></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="country_Err">Please select your     country</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Gender :</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="rdio" value="male" /> Male
                    <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="female" /> Female </td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="gender_Err">Please select    gender</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Preferences :</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="chk_Red" /> Red
                    <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Black" /> Black
                    <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Cyan" /> Cyan
                </td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="Name_Err">Please select   preference</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Phone :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="contact" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="contact_Err">Please enter valid   number</span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="con_Err">Only numbers</span> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="emil_id" id="check_email" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="Name_Err">Please enter valid  email</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Password( 6-8 characters) :</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pssword" id="pasword" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red;display:none" id="password_Err">Enter valid password!</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_Side">Verify Password :</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="verfy_password" id="vry_pasword" /></td>
                <td><span style="color:red;display:none" id="Pass_Err">Different from password!</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><br />
                    <br />
                    <br /></td>
                <td><input style="margin-left:0px" id="submit_Button" type="submit" value="SEND" />
                    <input style="margin-left:20px" id="reset_Button" type="reset" value="CLEAR" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't you think `. class="left_Side"` is wrong in the css part

Comment: did you include jQuery in the page, any other error in your browser console

Comment: You have `$(...).match is not a function` in your console....

Comment: whatever you said i did but when i run this code errors comes and goes within fraction of second.

Comment: and you deleted that onsubmit=return ValidateForm(), than why you mentioned that function in jQuery? How it can find that method if it not there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now in the else as well, you were matching the regex with the element , what actually you want is match its value.

**Update**

to check whether checkbox is checked or not give them same class and check whether any of them is checked or not.

```js
function ValidateForm() {
 var err = true;
    alert("in submit");
    if ($("#name").val() == null || $("#name").val() == "") {
        alert("in if");
        $("#name_Err").show();
        $("#name").focus();
        err = false;
    } else {
        $("#name_Err").hide();
        if (!$("#name").val().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
            alert("i m in regu");
            $("#name").focus();
            err = false;
        }
    }
    
    if($(".color:checked").length>0){
     alert('checkbox is checked do what ever you want to do');
      
    } 
    else{
       alert('check atleast one checkbox');
        err = false;
    }
    return err;
   }
```

```css
 .form {
      margin - left: 450 px;
      width: auto;
      height: 500 px
  }
  .class = "left_Side" {
      text - align: left;
      width: 80 px;
      position: absolute;
      padding - left: 50 px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();" action="" class="form">
    <table id="form_Table">
        <tr>
            <h1 style="text-align:Left; margin-left:20px;"> Javascript Validation</h1>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Name :</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="name_Err">Please enter your         name</span></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="na_Err">Only   alphabets</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Address :</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="address" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="address_Err">Please enter your   address</span></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="add_Err">Only alphabets</span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Zip Code :</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="zip_code" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="zipCode_Err">Please enter your    zip code</span></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="zip_Err">Only numbers</span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Country :</td>
            <td><select id="country_Select">
   <option value="">Select Country</option>
   <option value="opt_India">India</option>
   <option value="opt_Australia">Australia</option>
   <option value="opt_America">America</option>
  </select></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="country_Err">Please select your     country</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Gender :</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="rdio" value="male" /> Male
                <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="female" /> Female </td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="gender_Err">Please select    gender</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Preferences :</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="chk_Red" class="color" /> Red
                <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Black" class="color"/> Black
                <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Cyan" class="color"/> Cyan
            </td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="Name_Err">Please select   preference</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Phone :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="contact" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="contact_Err">Please enter valid   number</span></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="con_Err">Only numbers</span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="emil_id" id="check_email" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="Name_Err">Please enter valid  email</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Password( 6-8 characters) :</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pssword" id="pasword" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red;display:none" id="password_Err">Enter valid password!</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_Side">Verify Password :</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="verfy_password" id="vry_pasword" /></td>
            <td><span style="color:red;display:none" id="Pass_Err">Different from password!</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br />
                <br />
                <br /></td>
            <td><input style="margin-left:0px" id="submit_Button" type="submit" value="SEND" />
                <input style="margin-left:20px" id="reset_Button" type="reset" value="CLEAR" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: how can i achieve this using for loop.??                                                if(!($("input[type='radio']").is(":checked")))
  {
   $("#gender_Err").fadeIn(2000);
   err = false;   
  }
  else
  {
   $("#gender_Err").fadeOut(2000);
  }

Comment: you need loop for what ? you want to loop on each element of form and validate it?

Comment: I have checkboxes more than 5 so how can i check wheather any checkbox is checked or not using for loop or whatever way which is simple to understand coz i'm new to jQuery

Comment: @Shanky checkbox validation is done, ans is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `match()` on a jQuery object, instead of the value of the input field resulting in an error like `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).match is not a function` in your console

```
if (!$("#name").val().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
    ....
}
```

Also since you are using jQuery, there is no need to use a inline `onsubmit="return ValidateForm();"` handler, instead use a jQuery submit handler - not a submit button click handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var err = true;
  $('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function ValidateForm() {
    alert("in submit");
    if ($("#name").val() == null || $("#name").val() == "") {
      alert("in if");
      $("#name_Err").show();
      $("#name").focus();
      err = false;
    } else {
      $("#name_Err").hide();
      if (!$("#name").val().match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
        alert("i m in regu");
        $("#name").focus();
        $("#na_Err").show();
        err = false;
      } else {
        $("#na_Err").hide();
      }
    }

    return err;
  });
});
```

```css
.form {
  margin-left: 450px;
  width: auto;
  height: 500px
}
.left_Side1 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="" class="form">
  <table id="form_Table">
    <tr>
      <h1 style="text-align:Left; margin-left:20px;"> Javascript Validation</h1>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Name :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="name_Err">Please enter your         name</span>
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="na_Err">Only   alphabets</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Address :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="address" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="address_Err">Please enter your   address</span>
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="add_Err">Only alphabets</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Zip Code :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="zip_code" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="zipCode_Err">Please enter your    zip code</span>
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="zip_Err">Only numbers</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Country :</td>
      <td>
        <select id="country_Select">
          <option value="">Select Country</option>
          <option value="opt_India">India</option>
          <option value="opt_Australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="opt_America">America</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="country_Err">Please select your     country</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Gender :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="male" />Male
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="female" />Female</td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="gender_Err">Please select    gender</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Preferences :</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Red" />Red
        <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Black" />Black
        <input type="checkbox" value="chk_Cyan" />Cyan
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="Name_Err">Please select   preference</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Phone :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="contact" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="contact_Err">Please enter valid   number</span>
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="con_Err">Only numbers</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Email:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="emil_id" id="check_email" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red; display:none" id="Name_Err">Please enter valid  email</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Password( 6-8 characters) :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="pssword" id="pasword" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red;display:none" id="password_Err">Enter valid password!</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_Side">Verify Password :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="verfy_password" id="vry_pasword" />
      </td>
      <td><span style="color:red;display:none" id="Pass_Err">Different from password!</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="margin-left:0px" id="submit_Button" type="submit" value="SEND" />
        <input style="margin-left:20px" id="reset_Button" type="reset" value="CLEAR" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: ok till now its working thanx, but could you tell how i can create validation for gender using for loop